# Insertion sort - how it works

Tags: sorting

[image]

This is the pseudocode for insertion sort.

My question is this: suppose I have the array [5,2,4,6,1,3].

key = 2 and i = 1. Then A[i+1] = A[i] is A[2] = A(1) = 5. So now isn't the new array [5,5,4,6,1,3]?  Where in the pseudocode does it write the 2 into the first place, i.e: A(1) = A[2]?

Edit: I think I realised my mistake. key = A[j] stores the 2 and then at the end it writes it over the 5 that is in the first spot, to make the array: [2,5,4,6,1,3]

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER**SCIENCE** @SE. For content you did not create yourself, please [state who did and where you got it](/help/referencing). Among things not (overly) welcome are *using an image to present text* and *check my answer* questions - and `Edit:`: there is an edit history accessible with the middle hyperlink beneath a post. Pseudocode is preferred over source code in a concrete programming language. You could have used the step/line numbers to spare the reader some searching.

Comment: It is sorted correctly for i = 1: [2,5,4,6,1,3], all elements up to i = 1 are sorted. The next iterations would be i = 2: [2,4,5,6,1,3], then i = 3: [2,4,5,6,1,3], then i = 4: [1,2,4,5,6,3], finally i = 5: [1,2,3,4,5,6].